# Given a flight path given in latitudes and longitudes, how do I find another flight path that is parallel to the path given?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, spherical-geometry

Given a flight route that is given in latitudes and longitudes, how do I find another route that is "parallel" to the route given (find a perpendicular line to each waypoint given)? I think the best way to do this is to transform the geographic coordinates to Cartesian and find the parallel route and then converted it back to geographic coordinates but I never get it right. I tried the following approach also but I am not 100% sure if this is correct and I never get the last point of the "parallel" flight path:

Comment: Is this assuming the flight paths are on the same altitude? you want find the intersecting point?

Comment: There are an infinite number of *segments* which are perpendicular to a route at a point, but how can a *route* be defined to be perpendicular to another route?

Comment: It's just a spheroidal trig problem. I've solved buffer construction in both 'C' and Java. You just need a reliable function library to solve bearing and distance from two points, and new point from point, bearing and distance. After that it is just a construction exercise.

Comment: It's not the points that are important, per se, it's the segments -- for each segment, calculate bearing and distance, then construct points 90 degrees (pi/2) offset (+/-) from that bearing.  If your math is right, a simple parallel line is just the same bearing and distance from the new point.  With spheriodal support code, there's no need to waste time with Cartesian conversion.

Comment: perpendicular from origine?

Comment: That's why I said you need those support functions.  Once you have an inverse() and a direct(), this problem solves itself.

Comment: I've added a couple of relevant tags: [spherical-geometry] and [projection] -- see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spherical-geometry?sort=frequent
 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection?sort=frequent

Comment: Do you mind further editing the extra information into the question, please? It improves its quality and "answerability".

Comment: I obtained those functions by porting the US National Geodetic Survey FORTRAN source; having done this 20 years ago, I wouldn't recommend this path now.  But I do recommend researching the problem enough to understand why your initial attempts failed, so you can then choose wisely among your options.  A google on "geodetic inverse problem" should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to compute a parallel path.  Initial path is Moscow to
Sevastopol.  First, I assume that the waypoints lie on a geodesic.  So
the perpendicular direction is found just by adding 90° to the
azimuth of the geodsic.  Next I treat the more general case where there
may be changes in direction at the way points; for this I compute a mean
direction at each way point and subtract (for the sake of variety)
90° from this.  This uses my MATLAB package [Geodesics on an ellipsoid of revolution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3910):

```
lat1=55.41; lon1=37.91; % Moscow
lat2=44.68; lon2=33.58; % Sevastopol
nseg=10; % number of segments
t=50000; % offset

[s12,azi1,azi2] = geoddistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2);
[lata,lona,azia] = geodreckon(lat1,lon1,[0:nseg]*s12/nseg,azi1);

% offset waypoints assuming original path is a geodesic
[latb,lonb] = geodreckon(lata,lona,t,azia+90);

% don't assume waypoints lie on a geodesic
[~,azix,aziy] = geoddistance(lata(1:end-1),lona(1:end-1),...
               lata(2:end),lona(2:end));
dazi=azix(2:end)-aziy(1:end-1);
dazi=mod(dazi+180,360)-180;
% the average azimuth at the waypoints
azic=[azix(1),aziy(1:end-1)+dazi/2,aziy(end)];
% use sec to do a miter join
[latc,lonc] = geodreckon(lata,lona,t*secd([0,dazi/2,0]),azic-90);

plot(lona,lata, lonb,latb, lonc,latc);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *project* (transform) to plane coords, do the *coordinate geometry* (cogo), and project back to geographic coords, you must first choose the *right* map projection to use. There are very many and each introduces some distortions.

Another option is to stay on the sphere, and perform *spherical* (or geodetic) coordinate geometry. Those are much more complex, but you eliminate having to choose a projection.

Consider using the [GEOS - Geometry Engine, Open Source](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/), the [PROJ.4 - Cartographic Projections Library](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/), and other libraries.